# AttributeError using decorators

Tags: python, loops, decorator, attributeerror

I have recently learned about decorators and tried to implement them into my code. In the code below I made a decorator function that loops through data and plots it. This decorator function called "gridfunc" is then used to decorate "PlotTest()". PlotTest() takes in the function "SplitLow()", which has a looping variable as input. When I run this code I get the error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'Split'. I have searched online and found: 'int' object has no attribute" occurs when we try to access an attribute that doesn't exist on an integer. However, the input in Split should be an integer in order to acces different columns of Data, right?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Length = 3000
Data = [[np.mgrid[0:Length], np.mgrid[0:Length]], [np.mgrid[0:Length], 
np.mgrid[0:Length]]]

class Plot:
    def __init__(self, Data):
        self.Data = Data
 
    def Split(self,j):
        self.x = Data[j][0] #Takes j-th element from Data and selects the first column
        self.y = Data[j][1]
    
    def gridfunc(PlotFunc):
        """decorator that loops through length of self.Data to create j plots
        It takes in a plotting functiong PlotFunc.
        """
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):

            for args in range(len(self.Data)):
            
                PlotFunc(args, **kwargs)
                if args == range(len(self.Data))-1: #EDIT: range() should 
                                                    #not be here

                    plt.xlabel("x")
                    plt.ylabel("y")         
        return wrapper
  
    @gridfunc
    def PlotTest(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Split(args) #Takes j as argument, defined in wrapper
        plt.plot(self.xlow, self.ylow)
       
Plot = Plot(Data)
Plot.PlotTest()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your `gridFunc` decorator is stripping the `self` arg when it calls the original function:

```
    def gridfunc(PlotFunc):
        """decorator that loops through length of self.Data to create j plots
        It takes in a plotting functiong PlotFunc.
        """
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            for args in range(len(self.Data)):
            
                PlotFunc(args, **kwargs)  # oops
                if args == range(len(self.Data))-1:
                    plt.xlabel("x")
                    plt.ylabel("y")         
        return wrapper
```

This has the effect of `args` (which is an `int`) being treated as `self`, causing an error when you call `self.Split`.

Change this line:

```
                PlotFunc(args, **kwargs)
```

to:

```
                PlotFunc(self, args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I note that there seems to be some confusion elsewhere in this code between `Data` and `self.Data`, and `args` and `*args`.  The inconsistent application of the `*` operator seems like you might end up with further errors where you're passing an `int` where a `list` is expected or vice versa, but I haven't walked through the code closely enough to figure out if that's actually the case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I put a range() infront of len(self.Data) which should not be there.